# SSD Performance for PHP?

Tags: mysql, php, ssd, sas

My programmer just built an application with PHP using Doctrine ORM (will be a high traffic social networking website), and it's very heavy in PHP/Apache and CPU. The queries are wonderfully fast, and MySQL is barely using any CPU, it's just Apache.

I was curious to if an SSD would help speed up PHP/Apache, because I know the bottleneck is in PHP reading multiple files, class files, and loading up a bunch of data.

So common sense makes me think if PHP is reading multiple PHP files, an SSD would only help as far as read/write?

I was thinking of doing a high performance SSD for the PHP application, but for user image uploads, I would just continue using a 15k SAS. Is there any performance issues regarding using an SSD in this kind of situation? And would it prove to help speed up PHP/Apache, and help the CPU problem out?

Comment: Switching to a long-lived application daemon would help more.

Comment: Unless PHP is constantly pulling different data from the disk, it'll get cached quick and never hit the disk again. I'm with Ignacio on this one. Adding RAM might increase the cache hit ratio too.

Comment: long-lived application daemon?

Comment: Andrew fashion, you do use a php opcode cacher, right?

Comment: Were testing without APC right now, because my programmer wants to see how it does without APC before turning it on. I currently only have 14,000 users, and only 100 signups per day, but as soon as I started marketing, I'll be looking at 1,000 signups per day.

Comment: Then an opcode cacher is probably what you need.

Comment: php-fpm could also be useful here

Comment: (nine years later) tf would have to be a high endurance enterprise flash SSD in any case with delayed flush, as PHP, like any dynamic engine will chew up that endurance. Even cron and sed will do this. A file re-written every minute for a year adds up.  /var is different as you are appending and rotating, with lesser performance requirements.

Answer (score 4):

The only time you'll get an increase in performance is if your system profiling shows that you're currently bottlenecked on disk I/O.  Does your system profiling show this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd better profile your code to see where bottlenecks really are, as good SSDs are pretty costly and (at first glance) won't give you that much performance gain for that money.

What's load level you have now? Is it test system or production server with 1000's of users on it?

Comment: Oh, I see number for the load up in the comments. But what hardware (CPU and RAM at least) you're put on it?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree wholeheartedly with that last comment.

SSD will make a massive enormously huge difference in performance.

Unfortunately, most administrators out there are ignorant of what they need
to do to properly setup SSD and the surrounding server system to make use
of the SSD performance so all they do instead is use SSD as a drop in replacement
for SATA and no that does not work to well.

It is something like buying a million dollar high end sports car and then using
it to drive only to and from work each day because you don't know how to drive it
to make use of it's potential.

Where I am at, we have properly tuned the systems across the board to make use of
the SSD drives and the difference is far beyond amazing and well worth it.

Comment: Yet you don't provide any suggestions for proper SSD tuning...